# Como Consulta entre duas dates php+mysql?

Tags: php, html, query

Eu consigo fazer a consulta entre duas datas. Porém, a consulta retorna datas além das que foram pesquisadas.

**Exemplo**:

A consulta entre 01-02-2000 e 02-02-2000

[image: Veja abaixo que a consulta retorna também 01-05-200 e 01-08-2000]

Abaixo é o meu código:

```
<?php
$condition = '';

      if(isset($_REQUEST['in_dataInicio']) and $_REQUEST['in_dataInicio']!=""){
           $condition .= ' AND columnDataNasc BETWEEN "'.$_REQUEST['in_dataInicio'].' "';
      }
      if(isset($_REQUEST['in_dataFinal']) and $_REQUEST['in_dataFinal']!=""){
           $condition .= ' AND "'.$_REQUEST['in_dataFinal'].'"';
      }
$userData   = $db->getAllRecords('tb_cruds','*',$condition,'ORDER BY C0_ID DESC');
?>


<?php
class Database{

/**
 * objeto de conexão com o banco de dados
 * @var \PDO
 */
protected $pdo;

/**
 * Conecte-se ao banco de dados
 */
public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
{
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

/**
 * Retornar a conexão pdo
 */
public function getPdo()
{
    return $this->pdo;
}

public function get($tableName,  $whereAnd = array(), $whereBetween = array(), $whereOr=array(), $whereLike =array())
{
$cond   =   '';
$s=1;
$params =   array();
foreach($whereAnd as $key => $val)
{
    $cond   .=  " And ".$key." = :a".$s;
    $params['a'.$s] = $val;
    $s++;
}
foreach($whereOr as $key => $val)
{
    $cond   .=  " OR ".$key." = :a".$s;
    $params['a'.$s] = $val;
    $s++;
}
foreach($whereLike as $key => $val)
{
    $cond   .=  " OR ".$key." like '% :a".$s."%'";
    $params['a'.$s] = $val;
    $s++;
}
foreach($whereBetween as $key => $val)
{
    $cond   .=  " OR ".$key." between '% :a".$s."%'";
    $params['a'.$s] = $val;
    $s++;
}
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT  $tableName.* FROM $tableName WHERE 1 ".$cond);
    try {
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if (! $res || count($res) != 1) {
           return $res;
        }
        return $res;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("[".$e->getCode()."] : ". $e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function getAllRecords($tableName, $fields='*', $cond='', $orderBy='', $limit='')
{
    //echo "SELECT  $tableName.$fields FROM $tableName WHERE 1 ".$cond." ".$orderBy." ".$limit;
    //print "<br>SELECT $fields FROM $tableName WHERE 1 ".$cond." ".$orderBy." ".$limit;
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE 1 ".$cond." ".$orderBy." ".$limit);
 //    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM $tableName WHERE 1 ".$cond." ".$orderBy." " );
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
}
```

}
?>

Comment: o tipo do seu campo `C6_DataNasc` é `date`, `datetime`, `varchar` ou `char`?

Comment: O tipo de campo é varchar, pois, é apenas para data de nascimento, eu uso outras colunas para registrar a data de criação e a data de modificação.

Comment: Neste caso você precisa converter o campo para data na instrução SQL ou alterar o tipo do campo para `date`, eu sempre utilizo datas como datas, justamente para não perder funcionalidades com data.

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar o `BETWEEN` corretamente é necessário ter datas para comparação, se houver texto a comparação não irá dar certo mesmo, neste caso.

Para isso temos duas opções, alterar o tipo do campo para `date` ou converter no próprio comando.

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(C6_DataNasc, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '01-02-2000' AND '02-02-2000';
```

Comment: Resolvido. Obrigado pela a ajuda!